# Draw tangents from point to ellipse using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I'd like to create an ellipse (using psellipse, say).  Call it E.  And I'd like to specify a point P outside E.  And then I'd like to construct, using PSTricks, the two rays starting at P and tangent to E.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I know I could do this by doing it for a circle and then "stretching" the picture to make it an ellipse, but that complicates other things I'd like to do.  And of course one could figure this all out using explicit computations.  But I'd like to know if there is some simple straightforward way.

Comment: Are you sure stretching "circle-point tangency system" equals to "ellipse-point one"?

Comment: @xport: linear transformations don't change tangency (you can't get a second point of intersection by some stretching).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now in pstricks-add:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-2)(4,3)
 \psEllipseTangents(0,0)(3,2)(4,3)\psdot(4,3)
  \pcline[linecolor=red,nodesepB=-15mm](4,3)(EllipseT1)
  \pcline[linecolor=red,nodesepB=-15mm](4,3)(EllipseT2)
  \psdots(EllipseT1)(EllipseT2)
 \psellipse[fillcolor=cyan!30,fillstyle=solid](0,0)(3,2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am waiting for the `algebraic` option for all tangents to conic curves. :-)

Comment: there will be a macro `\psEllipseTangents` which defines two nodes.

Comment: This is very nice.  It's just what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use `GeoGebra` to draw such Euclidean Geometry graphs. It has a friendly GUI and can export `PSTricks` code easily.

http://www.geogebra.org/cms/

[image]

Comment: the PSTricks export of geogebra is lousy ...

Comment: @Herbert: I agree. Usually the code exported by `GeoGebra` needs to be modified manually. But it's easy to use, no complex caculations are needed.

Comment: this is not my point. With PSTricks you also do not need complex calculations, because every macro which is useful will be part of the package, just like `\psEllipseTangents`. However, with a gui one should export the image to PDF and not to tikz or PSTricks ...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the [pst-eucl](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-eucl/) package.

Comment: It seems that `pst-eucl` can only draw tangents of circle. I'm not sure if there are some other subpackages.

Comment: It should be submitted as a comment as it is too short as an answer.